# Color each errorbar with different color

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot an `errorbar` graph where each error bar may be either, say, red or green depending on whether the statistics used to compute the bar are significant.
I tried using an array of colors as an input to the `c` parameter, but that didn't work.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
yerrs = np.array([quantiles[:,2],quantiles[:,3]])
print yerrs.shape
colors = ['r', 'b'] * (yerrs.shape[1]/2)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
axes[0].errorbar(quantiles[:,0],quantiles[:,1], yerr=yerrs, c=colors)
axes[0].axhline(0, color='black')
axes[0].axvline(0, color='black')
axes[0].set_title('Fitted dist')
```

I then get the error:

```
ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "['r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b', 'r', 'b']"
could not convert string to float: r
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

separate your data array into two groups and use "ecolor" to specify errorbar color.

```
axes[0].errorbar(x1, y1, yerr=yerr1, ecolor="r")
axes[0].errorbar(x2, y2, yerr=yerr2, ecolor="b")
```

How to separate data into portions 1 and 2 should be trivial to you, but let me know if you are uncertain.

Comment: Thanks! That is almost exactly what I was trying to do, except that the line connecting the points is separate for each of the plots. Would be great if they could be on the same line.

Comment: @user1094206 not sure what you mean exactly --- you want them to be on the same line, then plot them using the same x and y rather than x1/2 and y1/2....