# Error bars in different colors with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code, that produces a simple graph with both vertical and horizontal error bars:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[2,3]
error_x=[0.5,0.4]
y=[25,28]
error_y=[0.6,0.8]
lines={'linestyle': 'None'}
plt.rc('lines', **lines)
pl.plot(x, y, 'ro', markersize=6)
pl.errorbar(x, y, xerr=error_x, yerr=error_y, fmt='b')
pl.xlim(1.3,3.6)
pl.ylim(24.0,29.0)
pl.show()
```

However, both error bars (vertical and horizontal) are blue, and I don't see how I could specify different colors for both of them. Is this possible? I would like, for example, for all horizontal error bars to be blue and for all vertical error bars to be green.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776761/color-each-errorbar-with-different-color

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `ecolor` keyword:

```
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[2,3]
error_x=[0.5,0.4]
y=[25,28]
error_y=[0.6,0.8]
lines={'linestyle': 'None'}
plt.rc('lines', **lines)
pl.plot(x, y, 'ro', markersize=6)
el = pl.errorbar(x, y, xerr=error_x, yerr=error_y, fmt='b', ecolor='yellow')
pl.xlim(1.3,3.6)
pl.ylim(24.0,29.0)
pl.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Different color lines, per bar and per orientation:

```
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[2,3]
error_x=[0.5,0.4]
y=[25,28]
error_y=[0.6,0.8]
lines={'linestyle': 'None'}
plt.rc('lines', **lines)
pl.plot(x, y, 'ro', markersize=6)
el = pl.errorbar(x, y, xerr=error_x, yerr=error_y, fmt='b', ecolor=['yellow','blue'])
elines = el.get_children()
elines[1].set_color('green')
pl.xlim(1.3,3.6)
pl.ylim(24.0,29.0)
pl.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: But in that case both horizontal and vertical error bars are yellow... I want the horizontal error bars to be one color, and the vertical ones another color. Is that possible?

Comment: Hrm.. Let me check.

Comment: @WildFeather Woah. Yeah!  Check this out.

Comment: Whoa, that's great! But why does it give me this error? "ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "['yellow', 'blue']"
length of rgba sequence should be either 3 or 4"

Comment: Do you have more than two error bars on your plot?  You may need to create a longer list with different data.

Comment: Try going back to a single ecolor and see if this works.  `el = pl.errorbar(x, y, xerr=error_x, yerr=error_y, fmt='b', ecolor='red')`

Comment: No, I just copied and pasted the code on your answer... Does it work for you, literally like it's on the answer? I'm no expert in Python...

Comment: Yes, that works! But then all the bars are red again.

Comment: Maybe matplotlib version?  I am on '2.1.0'

Comment: Maybe... I'm on '1.5.1'. I'll try to fix it, don't worry, and thank you very much!

Comment: I just figured out another way to do it, which works with an older Python version, and posted it as an answer. Yours works fine in Python 3. Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

Another "trick" for people with an older matplotlib version:

```
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[2,3]
error_x=[0.5,0.4]
y=[25,28]
error_y=[0.6,0.8]
lines={'linestyle': 'None'}
plt.rc('lines', **lines)
pl.plot(x, y, 'ro', markersize=6)
pl.errorbar(x, y, xerr=error_x, yerr=0, fmt='b', ecolor='b')
pl.errorbar(x, y, xerr=0, yerr=error_y, fmt='g', ecolor='g')
pl.xlim(1.3,3.6)
pl.ylim(24.0,29.0)
pl.show()
```