# Seaborn/matplotlib scatter plot, add error bars specific color

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, errorbar

How can I add error bars to a scatterplot, and control the color of the error bar?

For example, I have this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "x_mid": [0.5, 0.6, 0.2, 0.1],
        "x_low": [0.41, 0.55, 0.18, 0.02],
        "x_high": [0.66, 0.62, 0.3, 0.4],
        "x_col": ["black", "black", "red", "black"],
        "y_mid": [0.4, 0.45, 0.33, 0.12],
        "y_low": [0.35, 0.42, 0.3, 0.1],
        "y_high": [0.5, 0.5, 0.38, 0.22],
        "y_col": ["red", "black", "red", "black"],
    }
)

display(df)
```

[image]

And here is the scatterplot. I am using Seaborn here, but will also consider answers using Matplotlib directly.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))

g=sns.scatterplot(
    ax=ax,
    data=df,
    x="x_mid",
    y="y_mid",
)

ax.plot([0, 0.8], [0, 0.8], color="black", linewidth=1)
ax.set(xlim=(0, 0.8), ylim=(0, 0.8))
ax.grid(b=True, which="major")
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.2))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(0.2))
```

[image]

The "x_col" and "y_col" fields are the color for the error bar. So for the first row entry, the x range is (0.41, 0.66) and I want that to be a black error bar; and the y range is (0.35, 0.5), and I want that to be a red error bar, as sketched below.

How can I add error bars, based on the x_ and y_ range in the dataframe, and control the color of the error bars?

Using Python 3.8.3, Matplotlib 3.2.1, Seaborn 0.11.1

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47699783/6361531

Comment: Thank you, not sure how I missed this. That answer my question, so, this post can be closed,